# Issue with AJAX Post Method to use in code-behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am looking for help with sending JSON data via an Ajax method to a url, that I can then access to use the values of. I think I have most of the components but I am unsure what to do once I get to my Web Method. Are there any errors leading up to getting to my Web Method?. Also, I've searched thru about 20 similar examples on Stack Overflow and whilst some of them may have been the solution for my problem, I either didn't understand it or missed it.

My script

```
function UpdatePeople() {
        var PeopleToUpdate = {
            "people": [
                { "name": "John", "age": "17" },
                { "name": "Harry", "age": "19" },
                { "name": "Steve", "age": "23" }
            ]
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '_ajax_updatepeople.aspx/UpdateOnDemand',
            type: "POST",
            data: PeopleToUpdate,
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }
```

My page (C#).

```
[WebMethod]
public string UpdateOnDemand(List<string> PeopleToUpdate)
{
    // what do i do now once i am here? How can i access the data I have sent through?
}
```

Comment: You are trying to send list of people object to server but your `UpdateOnDemand` accepts list of string? Do you want to send names of people or  something? Maybe do you want to send all people object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here that you are trying to send list of `people` to server, however your `UpdateOnDemand` method accepts list of `string`. I assume that you want to send list of people to server and you have `people` class on server. In addition, you need to use `JSON.stringify` to send list of people data:

So, client side:

```
function UpdatePeople() {
    var PeopleToUpdate = [
            { "name": "John", "age": "17" },
            { "name": "Harry", "age": "19" },
            { "name": "Steve", "age": "23" }
        ];

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '_ajax_updatepeople.aspx/UpdateOnDemand',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({'PeopleToUpdate' : PeopleToUpdate }),
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Server side :

```
[WebMethod]
public string UpdateOnDemand(List<People> PeopleToUpdate)
{
    //..
}
```

And `People` class on server side should be like this:

```
public class People
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Selim. Thanks for your post and i think you'e got me going on the right track. I've used your suggested changes and now when running I get this outputting to the Console. Uncaught TypeError: JSON.Stringify is not a function. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried removing the JSON.Stingify from the data attribute of the .ajax call and it at least did not 'error'. Not sure if the data is in the right format at the other end, though i'm guessing it's not.

Comment: Ok, some more troubleshooting from me. Should it be Stringify with a lower case 's'? I've now gone beyond where it was failing before and now have another error which i should be able to work out (500 error), but i think it might be 'stringify' and not 'Stringify' ?

Comment: Yes my mistake, it should be with lower case 's'. I have updated my answer